# ul li last element align

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a huge issue with this code. I have read all the posts related to this subject and I think I am dumb or something. LOL. I could not make mine work.

Here is the site (please view in Chrome):
http://tinyurl.com/okfo53p
and here is the simplified code IMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/r8Rc9/4/

```
<div id="menubar" align="center">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="home"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="services"><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
        <li class="enquiry"><a href="enquiry.html">Enquiry</a></li>
        <li class="aboutaal"><a href="aboutall.html">About AAL</a></li>
        <li class="contactus"><a href="contactus.html">Contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<style>
#menubar { height:50px; width:735px;}
#menubar ul { display:inline;}
#menubar li { margin:0 0 0 0; padding:0 0 0 0; border:0; list-style-type:none; display:block; float:left;}
#menubar li a:link, #menubar li a:visited { display:block; height:50px; width:147px;}
</style>
```

Can you please help me align that last li, as in Chrome has just gone mad.
Thank you.
Appreciated.

Comment: Remove `width:735px;` from `#menubar`.

Comment: Insufficient width nothing else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define your style sheet this `css`

```
#menubar ul {
display: block;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r8Rc9/6/)**

Comment: Though all versions work, this is the one I was looking for. Thank you Azad.

Answer (score 2):

You need to increase the `width` of `#menubar`

**For Instance,**

```
#menubar {
    height:50px;
    width:775px;
    }
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r8Rc9/8/)**

Comment: Noup... 147x5=735. I am sorry, but not the way it should be done. Thank you.

Comment: 147x5 = 735, then what about margins, paddings and borders?? You need to recalculate - @user3048208

Comment: margins and borders were set to 0 weren't they?

Answer (score 1):

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r8Rc9/9/)

remove `float:left;` from `li` and add `float:left;` to `a tag.`

```
#menubar {height:50px;width:735px;}
#menubar ul { display:inline;}
#menubar li { margin:0 0 0 0; padding:0 0 0 0; border:0; list-style-type:none; display:block;}
#menubar li a:link, #menubar li a:visited { display:block; height:50px; width:147px; float: left;}
```

Comment: This does not work in the page itself, but indeed works in http://jsfiddle.net/r8Rc9/9/. No clue why. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="menubar" align="center">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="home"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="services"><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
        <li class="enquiry"><a href="enquiry.html">Enquiry</a></li>
        <li class="aboutaal"><a href="aboutall.html">About AAL</a></li>
        <li class="contactus"><a href="contactus.html">Contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<style>
#menubar { height:50px; width:735px;}
#menubar ul { display:inline;}
#menubar .menu li { margin:0 0 0 0; padding:0 0 0 0; border:0; list-style-type:none; display:block; float:left;}
#menubar .menu li a:link, #menubar li a:visited { display:block; height:50px; width:147px;}
#menubar .menu li:last-child{
  /*do something with last li*/
}
</style>
```

Comment: It works with last child, but more code for a simpler solution. Not me. Thank you.